# Delete a single user in a group - Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models `Group` and `Person`. both are HABTM, but I want a Person to have the ability to sign out of a specific group without deleting that group, just the person from the group. I've been trying figure this out in the console and I can't seem to get it. I'll show my code for clarification.

I'm making this method currently

```
def delete_from_group(phone_number)
 person = Person.find_by(phone_number: phone_number)
 person.groups.destroy
end
```

this is my controller.

```
def create
# Grab the phone number from incoming Twilio params
@phone_number = params[:From]
# Find the subscriber associated with this number or create a new one
@subscriber = Person.find_or_create_by(phone_number: @phone_number)
@delete_group = Person.find_by(phone_number: @phone_number)

# Update location data
@subscriber.update(
  city: params[:FromCity],
  state: params[:FromState],
  zip: params[:FromZip],
  country: params[:FromCountry]
)

@body = params[:Body].to_s.downcase.strip
begin
  # Process the command from our Subscriber
  output = process_message(@body, @subscriber, @delete_group)
rescue
  output = "Something went wrong. Try again."
end

# Render the TwiML response

respond(output)
end

private

def process_message(message, subscriber, delete_group)
if worker_groups.include?(message)
  subscriber.update(subscribed: true)
  subscriber.add_to_group(message)
  "You have been subscribed to the #{message.capitalize} list"

elsif message == "stop volunteer"
  delete_group.delete_from_group("volunteer")
  "You have been unsubscribed from the specified list"
elsif message == "stop dancer"
  delete_group.delete_from_group("dancer")
  "You have been unsubscribed from dancer list"
elsif message == "stop staff"
  delete_group.delete_from_group("staff")
  "you have been unsubscribed from staff list"

elsif message == "tulip" || message == "stem"
  subscriber.update(subscribed: message == "tulip")
  subscriber.add_to_group("visitor")

  if subscriber.subscribed
    "You are now subscribed for updates."
  else
    "You have unsubscribed from notifications. Text 'TULIP' to start receieving updates again."
  end
else
  "Sorry, we don't recognize that command. Available commands are: 'TULIP' or 'STEM'."
end
end

def worker_groups
%w(dancer staff volunteer)
end

def worker_groups
 %w(dancer staff volunteer)
end
```

Comment: We'll need more information about how `Person` and `Group` are connected. Might help to show what the method `add_to_group` is doing, or showing the association in each model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have the group id you want to remove as variable group_id:

```
 person = Person.find_by(phone_number: phone_number)
 group = person.groups.find(group_id)

 if group
    person.groups.delete(group)
 end
```

See [this awesome post on the subject](http://neyric.com/2007/07/08/how-to-delete-a-many-to-many-association-with-rails/)

Also see the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many):

> collection.delete(object, …) Removes one or more objects from the
>   collection by removing their associations from the join table. This
>   does not destroy the objects.

Comment: Would this not delete the group? The question is how to remove person from the group without deleting it.

Comment: If you read the post and the documentation (added above), it is clear that it just deletes it from the collection.

Comment: Backwards... it removes it from the collection by removing their ASSOCIATIONS. It does not destroy the group.

Comment: You are correct. I was not taking the HABTM join table into consideration. This works since it does destroy an object, it is just an object within a join table and not one of the original objects that are joined.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `has_many :through` instead of HABTM. That lets you delete the join table row directly as well as add metadata on the join table.

Provided you have a conventional setup you simply need to rename the table and change the relation definitions on the models.

```
class RenameGroupsPersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :groups_people, :memberships
  end
end
```

The rename is needed due to the way ActiveRecord resolves class names from tables. ActiveRecord will try to load `Groups::People` if the table is named `groups_people`. `GroupPeople` is just strange so lets go with `Membership`.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :people, through: :memberships
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :person
  validates_uniqueness_of :group_id, scope: :person_id
end
```

You can now remove rows directly from the join model association:

```
person.memberships.find_by(group_id: 5).destroy
```

Comment: This can seem like a pretty trivial improvement but HABTM only really works for the simplest possible kinds of relations and you usually need to switch over to `has_many :through` at some point. http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: I know I have another answer to this question, but if you have the time to make this change has_many :through really is the preferred way to go about this. Upvoted this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `Group` associations this way:

```
person.groups = []
person.save
```

Or:

```
person.update(groups: [])
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this would remove the person from ALL groups. If that is the intention, then this is an effective solution.